# if a in list (I want to add something to the element in list) Python

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement

As the topic states:

```
list = ["a", "b"]

element = "ac"
```

Can I use the:

```
if element in list:
```

If element is equal to the element in (list + "c")

Pseudocode to what I want to achieve:

```
if element in (list+c)
```

What is the best way to get this behavior in python?

**Edit:** I know there are many ways to get around this, but can this be done in one line as the code above.

Comment: Why not simply: element[0] in list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More efficient would be:

```
if any(x+'c' == element for x in your_list):
```

as it avoids scanning through the list twice (once to make the "+c" versions, once to check if element is in the resulting list). It'll also "short-circuit" (that is, quickly move on) if it finds the element before going through the entire list.

---

P.S. - it's best not to name variables `list`, since that's already the name for the actual list *type*.

Comment: @ThiefMaster er, what? The OP is asking about concatenating "c" onto each of the strings in the list, not adding a new string to the list.

Comment: Ah, thought he wanted to check if it's in the list or `'c'`

Comment: I have to say that while this might be more efficient, it is not as readable as `if element in (elem + 'c' for elem in your_list)`

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. "If any 'item plus c' equals what I'm looking for, for the items in this list" is still pretty readable, given what the OP is trying to check.

Answer (score 1):

```
if element in [elem + 'c' for elem in my_list]:
    # ...
```

Never a good practice to call a variable `list` (or `int`, `float`, `map`, `tuple`, etc.), because you are loosing those built-in types.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use a generator, not a list comprehension? e.g. `if element in (elem + 'c' for elem in my_list)`

Comment: I don't think you can use the `in` operator on generators; it might never return (`-1 in itertools.count()` for example)

Comment: Thanks, that what i have been looking for. :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster You can use `in` on generators; using it on infinite iterables is just a bad idea. Sort of like using `while True` without a break statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
if element[0] in list:
```

You don't want to add `"c"` to every item in the list and check to see whether `"ac"` is in the resut; you want to check to see if the first letter of `"ac"` is in the list. It's the same thing except a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
if element[:-1] in list:
```

It is better to calculate the element without 'c'. So you are making just one calculation.